# animate an icon that is moving through GeoPoints

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-mapview, geopoints

i am developing an android application which is based on mapview. (a live real time bus timing application).

im using the "overlay" class for this purpose (inserting the icons etc').
i am recieving an array of GeoPoints, and i need to create an animation in which a certain icon is moving through the GeoPoints index route. (in short - an icon that represents a bus which is moving on a certain road / route)

how can this animation be achieved?

Comment: did you try something yet, and are there any problems you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

You need   first   remove previous overlay  item then add new overlay item with new Lat-Long points   when it received....that's  why  you need to use  broad cast receiver to get new  updated  location & code executes.,..

Answer (score -1):

Its not possible to animate an Overlay, you have to show all the route geopoint one by one on a single overlay.
I would suggest to create an TimerTask to iterate on placing Overlay with your points.( Only one point is visible at the same time. Change the timerTask speed to change the animation speed.(i think 100ms is good animation time)